# How to fail a test that is stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-2.0, mstest

I have some code that produces an infinite loop.  Now I need to write a test that will fail after about 200ms.  200ms will indicate that the code is in the infinite loop.

For example:

```
public void CodeUnderTest()
{
   while(true)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: You can use Test Timeouts Under the Test settings. Edit
add [TestMethod(), Timeout(ms)] at the start of each test. Or look in the testTimeout settings for test run wide timeouts

Comment: Insert "Halting problem" reference here.

Comment: How? This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Which framework are you using?  xUnit and MSTest have a [Timeout](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons) attribute for example.

Comment: Are you actually writing this against .NET 2.0?  It's 7 years old at this point, 3, 3.5, 4 and 4.5 have come since then.

Comment: In addition to writing a test as described, I think that the code ought to be modified as well. e.g. While true OR until some timeout reached. Otherwise your test could pass but the actual code could still fail.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - oh, the person who created all the other tests targeted 2.0,  we haven't converted our tests yet to the newer frameworks.

Comment: @MarkMaslar - Yes, perhaps I will make additional tests that test this functionality.

Comment: You can specify a timeout os an attribute on the method ("at the start of each test") and there's a setting in the Test Settings file that controls the timeout for all tests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

what about:

```
Task.Create(CodeUnderTest).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

or:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(CodeUndertest).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

or:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CodeUndertest(arg1,arg2,arg3...)).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Comment: sure it is, don't think that there's a framework-way to achieve the goal -- there shouldn't be any parts of code to test which run forever ;)

Comment: @TheHe - For some reason, Create does not exist for me?

Comment: @O.O Use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: uh.. task.create can be >=.net4 only...

check out edited one.

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 21):

When using MSTest you can use an attribute

```
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(200)]
```

See [How to force tests to stop running](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx)

> You can set time limits with which the execution of a test or a test run will 
>   comply. You might need to do this, for example, if you
>   work in a test lab and need a test run to complete by a certain time
>   of day.
>
> Another scenario for the use of time limits is that of non-responsive code.

Comment: @TheHe - The result is TimeOut.

Comment: mh okay... HE must decide what behaviour to expect on this infinte task ;)

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - I do not know why exactly, but when I tried this, the code still ran forever...

Comment: @TheHe - Well, that's how I interpret the halting problem.  In general, for complex problems we never know if a program will halt or continue on forever.  In this case, we can add a reasonable timeout and assume if it exceeds the timeout then the program hit an infinite loop.

Comment: imho, he does only want to know, if it will "fail in 500ms". if it runs longer, he will assume that it succeeds -- why? no idea, but this is what i got from the question ;)
"timeout" is an error-case in mstest, am i right? ;)